# Lifetime with exponential and Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, applications, exponential-distribution

The lifetime of an electronic device is a rv with exponential distribution ($\mu=1/10$). In a normal week, the hours that the device is used is a rv with Poisson distribution ($\lambda=12$). Calculate the probability that a new device, in a normal week, won't fail during that week.

I'm stuck with this type of problems. So far I have the following:

Let $X$: lifetime of an electronic device and $Y$: hours that the device is used. Then, I have to calculate $P[X>Y]$. So,

$$P[X>Y]=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}P[X>Y|Y=y]P[Y=y].$$

I have no idea if I can suppose that X and Y are independent.

Comment: For fixed $Y = y$, calculate $P[X > Y]$. Then average the resulting expression over $Y$. You just need to add a factor of $P[Y = y]$ to your sum. $X$ and $Y$ are certainly independent.

Comment: Thank you, I did it and you are right.

Comment: I got $\exp[\lambda (e^{-\mu} - 1)]$. Is that what you got?

Comment: I got $exp[-12(1-exp(-1/10))]$, it is almost the same but a sign

Comment: Now it is the same

Comment: That's exactly the same expression. A minus sign has just been shifted out of the parenthesis: $\lambda(e^{-\mu} - 1) = -\lambda (1 - e^{-\mu})$.

Comment: I'm already stuck with another problem, Im going to try a little bit harder and then ask. Hope to see you in that question. Thank you.